# Undefined control sequence on \beamer@leftmargin indentation

Tags: beamer

According to example from http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.8.2.2 the following code I think should work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{E}
\hskip-\beamer@leftmargin
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However compilation with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex` fails with subj error at line 180 of the log https://pastebin.com/HmRdN0Vc .

Can anyone explain what's going wrong here?

Comment: @siracusa Thank you for pointing to the right direction! Adding those commands around the frame environment solved the problem. Curiously, those commands seem to be disabled inside the frame environment.
I think your comment can be made into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` normally cannot be part of a command name because it has catcode 12 (other), while command name characters need to have catcode 11 (letter). The solution is to wrap your frame in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` to change the catcode of `@` properly (see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)):

```
\makeatletter
\begin{frame}{E}
\hskip-\beamer@leftmargin
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\makeatother
```

As for the issue of using these macros inside the frame, `beamer` doesn't seem to process the frame's content in normal paragraph building mode, but reads its content in form of the argument of a macro call. At that moment all catcodes inside the frame are fixed and cannot be changed anymore. `\makeatletter` thus won't have any effect. There's an option `fragile` to allow contents with catcode changes, though:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{E}
\makeatletter
\hskip-\beamer@leftmargin
\makeatother
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
```